# Setting amount of copies in ghostscript

Tags: command-line, ghostscript

we're trying to convert pdf's to ps files with ghostscript using the ghostscript commandline tool. Somehow we can't find a parameter to set the amount of copies that should be printed.
So if we'd want to print a file twice we'd have to send it two times, there should probably be a simple parameter that tells the printer to print this more often, but I can't find it. Can somebody help me out?

Thanks!

edit:

Converting PDF -> PS using

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE ^
  -sDEVICE=pswrite ^
  -sOutputFile=out.ps ^
   in.pdf
```

Working on windows..

Answer (score 1):

PDF files, unlike PostScript files, have no means for setting the number of copies. You don't say *how* you are printing the file, but I suspect that :

... -c "<<
/NumCopies 2>> setpagedevice" -f..."

would work. But without knowing what you are doing I can't be sure.

Comment: I want to set the number of copies in the postscript file! not the pdf!

Comment: First, don't use pswrite, its terrible, use ps2write. Secondly, just add the 'NumCopies' PostScript fragment to the generated PostScript from ps2write. You can do the same with the pswrite output if you prefer larger less portable PostScript :-)

Comment: The complete command (optimized for shortness) that KenS hinted to would read: `gswin32c.exe -o out.ps -sDEVICE=ps2write -c "<</NumCopies 2>> setpagedevice" -f in.pdf`

Comment: Does that actually do anything in the output PostScript file ? I expected it wouldn't.....